# Extra curly braces when using xtable and knitr, after specifiying size

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, xtable

I'm creating a R Markdown document using `knitr` and am running into trouble using `xtable` to create a table. My table is very large and I'm trying to reduce the size using the `size` command in the `print` statement. The issue I'm running into is that the command seems to add two extra curly braces which show up in the PDF, one before the table and one after.

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

MWE:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
tables: true
---

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}

library(xtable)

my.df <- data.frame(matrix(c(1:18),nrow=2))

glossaryprint <- xtable(my.df, caption="Summary of Terms")

print(glossaryprint,
      comment=FALSE,
      floating=FALSE,
      size="footnotesize"
)

```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:**  The issue that is subject of the question and this answer has been resolved in [`xtable` 1.8-2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/NEWS).

---

Although the question has been self-answered with a workaround, I think for other users some more details might be helpful.

### What happens?

To understand what is happening here, we need to take a close look at the conversion steps the document undergoes on its way from RMD to PDF. The steps are:

```
RMD --> MD --> TEX --> PDF
```

Let's look at the files in reversed order:

- `PDF`: (generated from `TEX` by `pdflatex`)

[image: PDF output]

- `TEX`: (generated from `MD` by `pandoc`)

  ```
  % …
  \{\footnotesize

  \begin{tabular}{rrrr}
    \hline
   & X1 & X2 & X3 \\ 
    \hline
  1 &   1 &   3 &   5 \\ 
    2 &   2 &   4 &   6 \\ 
     \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \}
   % …
  ```
- `MD` (generated from `RMD` by `knitr`)

  ```
  ---
  output:
    pdf_document:
      keep_tex: yes
  ---

  {\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{rrrr}
    \hline
   & X1 & X2 & X3 \\ 
    \hline
  1 &   1 &   3 &   5 \\ 
    2 &   2 &   4 &   6 \\ 
     \hline
  \end{tabular}
  }
  ```
- `RMD`: (source file)

  ````
  ---
  output:
    pdf_document:
      keep_tex: yes
  ---

  ```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}

  library(xtable)

  mytable <- xtable(data.frame(matrix(c(1:6), nrow = 2)))

  print(mytable,
        comment = FALSE,
        floating = FALSE,
        size = "footnotesize"
  )
  ```
  ````

Recall: The problem is, that there are visible curly braces in the `PDF`. Where do they come from?

- They are the result of the escaped curly braces in the `TEX` file (`\{` and `\}`).
- These curly braces also exist in the `MD` file, but there they are not escaped.

So we know two things by now: We see the curly braces because they are escaped and they are escaped by `pandoc`.

But why do these curly braces exist at all? `print.xtable` outputs them when a `size` is specified. The goal is to create a group and to apply `size` only within that group. (With `floating = TRUE`, no grouping by curly braces is required because there is a `figure` environment whithin which the `size` is set. The curly braces are printed anyways.)

And why does `pandoc` escape that pair of curly braces but leaves all the other curly braces (e.g. in `\begin{tabular}`) unescaped? This is because `pandoc` is supposed to escape special characters that are meant literally but leave [raw LaTeX unescaped](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#raw-tex). However, `pandoc` *does not know* that the outer curly braces are LaTeX commands and not text.

(With `floating = TRUE` the problem does not occur because the curly braces are within a `figure` environment which is recognized as LaTeX.)

### Solutions

After having understood the problem, what can we do about it? One solution has already been [posted by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33681917/2706569): Abstain from spefifying `size` in `print.xtable` and insert the `footnotesize` command manually:

````
    ---
    output:
      pdf_document:
        keep_tex: yes
    ---

    ```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}

    library(xtable)

    mytable <- xtable(data.frame(matrix(c(1:6), nrow = 2)))

    cat("\\begin{footnotesize}")

    print(mytable,
          comment = FALSE,
          floating = FALSE
    )

    cat("\\end{footnotesize}")
    ```
````

However, on the long run it would be nice if `xtable` (current version: `1.8-0`) generated LaTeX code that survives the `pandoc` conversion. This is quite simple: `print.xtable` checks if `size` is set and if so, inserts `{` before the size specification and `}` at the end of the table:

```
if (is.null(size) || !is.character(size)) {
  BSIZE <- ""
  ESIZE <- ""
}
else {
  if (length(grep("^\\\\", size)) == 0) {
    size <- paste("\\", size, sep = "")
  }
  BSIZE <- paste("{", size, "\n", sep = "")
  ESIZE <- "}\n"
}
```

This small modification replaces `{` with `\begingroup` and `}` with `\endgroup`:

```
if (is.null(size) || !is.character(size)) {
  BSIZE <- ""
  ESIZE <- ""
}
else {
  if (length(grep("^\\\\", size)) == 0) {
    size <- paste("\\", size, sep = "")
  }
  BSIZE <- paste("\\begingroup", size, "\n", sep = "")
  ESIZE <- "\\endgroup\n"
}
```

For LaTeX, this makes no difference, but as `pandoc` recognizes `\begingroup` (as oppsed to `{`) it should solve the problem. I reported this [as a bug](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6260&group_id=1228&atid=4861) in `xtable` and hopefully the issue will be fixed in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by not including the size parameter in the print statement but rather directly before and after the chunk.

```
\begin{footnotesize}

#chunk

\end{footnotesize}
```