# Changing fontsize of a single line in rmarkdown without altering global fontsize

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

How do I increase the fontsize of an equation on its own line in rmarkdown using knitr and pandoc without increasing the fontsize of the entire document?

I am knitting to PDF using knitr and pandoc.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example rmarkdown document. I wish to increase the fontsize on the single line with the maths equation ONLY, while leaving the two passages it either side of it subject to the global document font settings:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

The thing we all love about Stack Overflow is how helpful its users are. As long as you take the time to provide a worked example they will help you solve your problem.

*$Y_{ij}$* = [*$\beta_0$* + *$\beta_1$*(Dose-300)] + [*$\varepsilon_{ij}$*]

One day I hope to be able to provide answers to new users the way some helpful users did for me, a pay it forward if you will.
```

Comment: Is this about an arbitrary line of text, a paragraph of text or about a display equation? Please add a minimal example to the question, indicating which parts should change size and which should stay unaffected.

Comment: Sorry @CL, I have provided an example. I am referring to a display equation (i think. I don't know exactly what a display equation is but I have specified which text I want to change the fontsize of in the example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

With a minimal example of the problem, many questions can be answered easily.

\begingroup\Large
\begin{equation*}
Y_{ij} = [\beta_0 + \beta_1 (\text{Dose}-300)] + [\varepsilon_{ij}]
\end{equation*}
\endgroup

And usually, this is fun. ;-)
```

---

#### Longer answer

As far as I know, the only sensible output format for this is LaTeX anyways. Therefore, let's start with improving the equation's TEX code:

```
*$Y_{ij}$* = [*$\beta_0$* + *$\beta_1$*(Dose-300)] + [*$\varepsilon_{ij}$*]
```

becomes

```
$Y_{ij} = [\beta_0 + \beta_1 (\text{Dose}-300)] + [\varepsilon_{ij}]$
```

No need for the asterisks; math is typeset in italics anyways. No need to use separate `$...$` for each expression. Wrap `Dose` in `\text` to use upright font.

Next step: Increase the size. Basically, this is accomplished using `\Large`, but we need to tell LaTeX to enlarge the equation only. Usually, this can be done using curly braces like this: `{\Large ... }`. However, `pandoc` escapes `{`, so we need an alternative (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33689497/2706569) for a related problem and some explanations):

```
\begingroup\Large $Y_{ij} = [\beta_0 + \beta_1 (\text{Dose}-300)] + [\varepsilon_{ij}]$\endgroup
```

Or simply (but less elegant because dependent on the original font size):

```
\Large $Y_{ij} = [\beta_0 + \beta_1 (\text{Dose}-300)] + [\varepsilon_{ij}]$
\normalsize
```

We're basically done, but I suggest using [display mode](https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Mathematical_expressions#Mathematical_modes):

```
\begingroup\Large
\begin{equation*}
Y_{ij} = [\beta_0 + \beta_1 (\text{Dose}-300)] + [\varepsilon_{ij}]
\end{equation*}
\endgroup
```

As above, alternatively `\normalsize` could be used instead of the groupings.

Comment: Fantastic answer @CL, thank you so much. Worked like a charm. Not crucial but just out of interest is there any way to left-justify the equation?

Comment: You're welcome! Well, the second to last code snippet should be left justified; anything wrong with that one?

Comment: Yes you're right I actually noticed that when I included it in my document, without the \begin{equation*} and $'s in the code it left-justifies. Really useful. Thank you again.